7 segment display usage
The Digital trainer kit we are using has 7 segment display, I wish to use it to realise the output for the 3 bit counter. How exactly can I use it? Where to give inputs?
I'm attaching the picture of what I'm trying to do. What are A,b,c,d in the display?


Have you checked the manual?

I don't have one, this kit belongs to lab@RohatKılıç

It looks like it has converters built-in for converting binary to display patterns so just connect your counter outputs to A, B and C of one of the displays?

It's not displaying anything @Finbarr, I guess my circuit is wrong

Maybe you need to get power to it somehow

Can you add a picture of the whole board? I suppose this has some kind of common VDD and GND connections.

It appears to be a BCD-input 7-segment display.
You apply logic inputs to ABCD pins. Examples:



A
B
C
D
Number




0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
1
1


0
0
1
0
2


0
1
0
1
5


1
0
0
1
9



Could also be in the reversed order i.e. DCBA instead of ABCD.
